# Resources for setting up clustered FTP servers on CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos5, cluster, ftp

Does anyone have any resources that can lead me to a how-to or at least more information on setting up clustered FTP servers on CentOS?

I'm very new to servers in general (all I've done is set up a simple Linux box to run a Ruby on Rails app), so I'd really want a how-to if possible.

Furthermore, and this might be of the greatest importance: I have a server running **vsftpd** successfully. If all I'm missing is a few steps to get this server clustered with another, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "clustered"? Mutiple servers sharing a storage pool? Multiple servers with independent storage pools that sync to eachother? Something else?

Comment: The latter -- independent storage pools that sync to each other.